# Making a div appear outside of container in a responsive design

Tags: css, responsive-design, overflow

I'm trying to get some floated elements to appear outside of a container on a drupal page that is using a theme based on Omega. my page is currently structured as such:

```
<h2>Some header text</h2>
<div class="grid-12 region region-content center" id="region-content">
  <div class="container-12">
    <div class="pricing-main-background">
      <div class="grid-4 plan-box-orange">
      </div>
      <div class="grid-4 plan-box-green">
      </div>
      <div class="grid-4 plan-box-orange">   
      </div>
    <div class="pricing-subtext">
      some more text down here            
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Here's a sketch of what I'd like to accomplish (notice the smaller boxes outside of the container):

[Visual Aid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqXZ7.png)

Can anyone help provide a way to make this work (preferrably that doesn't require a mess of CSS when the boxes stack (at 480px)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
h2
{
    width:60%;
    border:1px solid black;
    border-bottom:0;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:center;
}
.grid-12
{
    width:60%;
    border:1px solid black;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:center;
}
.pricing-main-background {position:relative;}
.plan-box-orange {background:orange;}
.plan-box-green {background:green;}
.grid-4
{
    display:inline-block;
    width:30%;
    height:50px;
    margin-top:25px;
}
.grid-4:nth-of-type(1)
{
    position:absolute;
    left:-10%;
}
.grid-4:nth-of-type(3)
{
    position:absolute;
    right:-10%;
}
```

Comment: This is perfect. Using the nth-of-type selector will get me where I need to go. I can use some media queries to solve for the breakpoint.

Thanks, this helps a ton!